# Powershell regular expressions to match a number with no other numbers around

Tags: regex, powershell, sharepoint

In a Sharepoint Library, we have a custom field which is multi user field, the library stores employee Pictures.  However sometimes people leaves the company and we need to delete their pictures.

I created one script that does the following steps:

1. It makes a query to the entire library, to the multiple user field, and then gets a unique list.
2. For each user it will then query the list to see which specific list items have a picture of somebody that no longer works here.

The problem its that Sharepoint stores multiple people field like this:

```
57;#JohnSmith 56;#Johanna Smith
```

So, what I do is to compare with a match, but I dont get the results I want.

Example Results:

```
56;#John Smith
Picture1_2012_09_07_123jpg.jpg +  + 56;#John Smith
```

The first result is OK.

The second result however is like this:

```
WilliamGates_1jpg.jpg +  + 056;#William Gates (Not OK)
JeanClaudeVanDamme_2011_05_24__112jpg.jpg +  + 560;#JeanClaudeVanDamme (Not OK)
```

My script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.powershell

#$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
#Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest"

#. .\Functions-Logging.ps1

#Start-History -name "PDB Asset Cleaning"

$site = Get-SPSite https://oursharepointsite.com/sites/pdb/
$web = $site.RootWeb

$expiredAccountFound = $false

$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

$camlQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$camlQuery.Query = '<Where><And><Neq><FieldRef Name="ContentType" /><Value Type="Computed">Folder</Value></Neq><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="Persons_PDB" /></IsNotNull></And></Where>'
$camlQuery.ViewFields = '<FieldRef Name="Persons_PDB" />'
$camlQuery.ViewFieldsOnly = $true
$camlQuery.ViewAttributes = 'Scope="Recursive"'

$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("Assets")

$listItems = $list.GetItems($camlQuery)

$filteredItems = $listItems | ForEach-Object {$_.Item("Persons_PDB").LookupValue} | Select -Unique

$date = Get-Date

$fileName = "D:\Installers\PictureDB\R 1.0\Scripts\Add-ArtifactsToWeb\" + $date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/','-') + ".txt"

$message = "Report of " + $date.ToShortDateString() 
$message += "`r`n"
$message += "`r`n"

foreach($item in $filteredItems)
{
    $user = $web.EnsureUser($item)
    if (-Not $profileManager.UserExists($user.LoginName))
    {
        $loginName = $user.LoginName.Substring(13)
        Write-Host $loginName
        $userFromAD = Get-ADUser -Filter {SAMAccountName -eq $loginName}
        $concatenatedUser = $user.ID.ToString() + ";#" + $userFromAd.Name
        Write-Host  $concatenatedUser
        $query = [String]::Format("<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Persons_PDB' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='LookupMulti'>{0}</Value></Contains></Where>",$user.ID)
        $userItemsQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
        $userItemsQuery.Query = $query
        $userItemsQuery.ViewAttributes = 'Scope="Recursive"'
        $userItems = $list.GetItems($userItemsQuery)

        foreach($item in $userItems)
        {
           if($item["Persons_PDB"].ToString() -match $concatenatedUser)
           {
                write-host $item.File.Name +" " + $item["Persons_PDB"]

           } 

             #Write-Host $item . "will be deleted"
            #Write-Host $list.GetItemById($item.Id)
            #$list.GetItemById($item.Id).Recycle()
        }
    }
}





$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()

#Stop-History
```

Comment: `-match` is expecting `$concatenatedUser` to be a regular expression, but you are not supplying a RegEx.  Does it work with a simple '-eq` instead? The `#` in your string is likely confusing things as it has a special meaning (comment): [Regular Expression Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Comment: You could try `-match [Regex]::Escape($concatenatedUser)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might go with a different approach, which is splitting your multi-user string. This is a pain in your example because users are separated by spaces, but can also contain spaces. So we have to combine it with the predictable pattern at the beginning of the string to get a regex we can use to split it.

I modified your sample input string to the following for testing:

> `57;#JohnSmith 56;#Johanna Smith 59;#Alexander Graham Bell 060;#Persona Non Grata`

[We can use this regex pattern to split the string: `\s(?=\d+;#)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs%28%3F%3D%5Cd%2B%3B%23%29&i=57%3B%23JohnSmith%2056%3B%23Johanna%20Smith%2059%3B%23Alexander%20Graham%20Bell%20060%3B%23Persona%20Non%20Grata)

If you look at that link and click Split List you'll see this:

> 1. `57;#JohnSmith`
> 2. `56;#Johanna Smith`
> 3. `59;#Alexander Graham Bell`
> 4. `060;#Persona Non Grata`

### What does the RegEx do?

- `\s` - matches whitespace (you can replace this with a literal space if you want, or an escaped space `\`)
- `(?=...)` - a zero-width look-ahead, means whatever's in here must follow, but doesn't count as part of the match
- `\d+;#` - `\d+` means one or more digits, `;#` are literals (`#` only needs to be escaped in the regex mode where you can include comments)

So in summary, this pattern means: "match a space, but only if it's followed by 1 or more digits, then a semicolon, then a hash/pound/octothorpe (`#`).

### Why do this?

Because the `-split` operator can take a regex as the basis for when to split a string, into an array.

### Why use an array?

Because then you just check to see that the single user you're looking for is *in* the array:

```
foreach($item in $userItems)
{
   $persons = $item["Persons_PDB"].ToString() -split '\s(?=\d+;#)'
   if($concatenatedUser -in $persons) # or $persons -contains $concatenateduser
   {
        write-host $item.File.Name +" " + $item["Persons_PDB"]
   } 
}
```

---

#### Is what you're doing necessary at all?

I don't know. Without access to the objects it's hard to tell. But it does seem unlikely to me that SharePoint *stores* a multi-user field as a single string where multiple entries are separated by spaces *and* the entries themselves can contain spaces. Maybe you can already get it as an array? Maybe you can get ID alone and do some kind of direct comparison? Play around with the objects and the options you have for querying SharePoint and see if there's something you could that's more straightforward.